# Matrix multiplication using columns from a data frame as input?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

```
# Function to apply a rigid transformation matrix to a pair of coordinates
transformation <- function(r1, r2, r3, r4, x, y, z = 0, t = 1)
{
  transformation_matrix <- matrix(c(r1, r2, r3, r4), nrow=1, ncol=4)
  coordinate_matrix <- matrix(c(x, y, z, t), nrow=4, ncol=1)

  transformed_coordinate_matrix <- transformation_matrix %*% coordinate_matrix
  return(transformed_coordinate_matrix)
}
```

I wrote a function (see above) that takes in a LOT of parameters as input (disregard why I called them `r1, r2` etc. as it is not important to understand my issue). These parameters are used to construct 2 matrices that will be multiplied to form another matrix. This newly generate matrix is what the function returns. Instead of passing in a bunch of numbers, I would like to do the following:

1. Pass in a matrix instead of passing in numbers for the parameters `r1, r2, r3, r4`
2. For parameters `x` and `y`, I have a data frame with 2 columns representing the values I would like to pass into `x` and `y`.

`x  y
1 1 10
2 2 20
3 3 30
4 4 40
5 5 50`

I would like to somehow loop through these columns in this data frame and assign them to my parameters. This would mean I would be calling my `transformation()` function 5 times. One function call per row in the example data frame above. The other list of parameters would remain the same for each function call. It is just the `x` and `y` parameters that would change each time. I believe the `apply()` function will help me with this issue, though I am still learning R and am unsure how to do this.

Comment: can you change the number of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use `apply`

```
apply(df1, 1, function(u) transformation(r11, r12, r13, r21, r22, r23, r31, r32, r33, t1, t2, t3, x = u[1], y= u[2], z = 0, t = 1))
```

Comment: I get an error stating the following:Error in transformation_matrix %*% coordinate_matrix : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments. Do you mind explaining to how function(u) works?

Comment: @AdrianoMatos Can you please update your post with a reproducible example so that it can be tested

Comment: Looking back at your answer, this ended up fixing my issue. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Since `transformation_matrix` is constant you can take it out of the function.

```
transformation_matrix <- matrix(c(r11, r12, r13, t1, r21, r22, r23, 
              t2, r31, r32, r33, t3, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
```

and pass it as matrix to the function. Also no need to pass `x` and `y` separately, you can pass them together as a vector.

```
transformation <- function(t_mat, xy, z = 0, t = 1) {
   coordinate_matrix <- matrix(c(xy, z, t), nrow=4, ncol=1)
   transformed_coordinate_matrix <- t_mat %*% coordinate_matrix
   return(transformed_coordinate_matrix)
}
```

Now use `apply` rowwise to pass different values of `xy` to `transformation` function.

```
result <- apply(df, 1, transformation, t_mat = transformation_matrix)
```